# Cross-domain authentication not stored in Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, cross-domain

I have a `jQuery` `AJAX` request :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://xbo.dev/ajax/login_ajax',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            _username: $('#_username').val(),
            _password: $('#_password').val()
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
```

And a `PHP` controller :

```
    public function loginAjaxAction() {
        $request = $this->get('request');

        $success = false;
        $responseCode = 300;
        $authorizedHostsDev = array('xbo.dev');

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() || in_array($request->headers->get('host'), $authorizedHostsDev))) {
            $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserBy(array('username' => $request->request->get('_username')));

            if ($user) {
                $encoderManager = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
                $encoder = $encoderManager->getEncoder($user);
                $encodedPass = $encoder->encodePassword($request->request->get('_password'), $user->getSalt());

                if ($user->getPassword() === $encodedPass) {

                    if ($user->getExpiresAt() < new \DateTime()) {
                        $responseCode = 500;
                    } else {
                        $this->userAuthentication($user);

                        $responseCode = 200;
                        $success = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    $responseCode = 400;
                }
            }

        }
        $return = json_encode(array('responseCode' => $responseCode, 'success' => $success));
        return new Response($return, 200, array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
    }
```

If I execute this `AJAX` request from xbo.dev, I have this result in the `console.log(data)` :

```
{"responseCode":200,"success":true}
```

After that, I'm redirected and I'm logged in.

If I execute this `AJAX` request from subdomain like blog.xbo.dev, I have the same result in `console.log(data)` but, when the page is refreshing, I'm not redirected (I stay on the connection page) and it seems that my login action is not made (still can enter my ids to connect).

How can I change this behavior ?

Thanks

EDIT : I just added one test, to know if I was connected in the moment, in the `PHP` controller. Indeed, even after the `AJAX` request from blog.xbo.dev, `$responseCode` is `1000`. The test :

```
if ($this->getUser()) {
    $responseCode = 1000;
} else {
    $responseCode = 200;
    $success = true;
}
```

EDIT 2 : Here is the code of the userAuthentication method :

```
private function userAuthentication(UserInterface $user) { 
    $providerKey = 'main'; // firewall name
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());

    $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
}
```

Comment: what does the debug bar say at the bottom, are you logged in as the user?

Comment: With xbo.dev, yes, but with blog.xbo.dev, I'm still anonymous.

Comment: when you try to log in from blog.xbo.dev, you're not logged in on BOTH  xbo.dev and blog.xbo.dev is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right, but if I try to log in from xbo.dev, I'm logged in on both xbo.dev and blog.xbo.dev

Comment: @deeznutz : I just edited my question with one test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I found.

I figured out that from my subdomain blog.xbo.dev, my `PHP` controller couldn't set the cookie for my authenticated user.

So, I just thought about it and decided to specially create a different route for my subdomain.

I precised the `host` parameter in my routing.yml.

So, I have one route called with `host: blog.xbo.dev` and the second one called with `host: xbo.dev`. Both of the 2 routes target the same PHP controller function (`loginAjaxAction`) and it works perfectly.

Hope this will help.